# Kivy touch registers y-axis lower than touched

Tags: python, kivy

Im not sure if its my version of kivy only but when i touch the screen, the touch registers in the correct x spot but the y spot hits lower by about 22 pixels making the top of screen buttons hard to press or wonky. I have tried looking at transforming the touch with `touch.apply_transform_2d(self.touch_trans)` if device is wm_touch and self.touch_trans is 
   `def touch_trans(self):
    return (x, y + 22)` which registers the difference but it registers on_touch_move because of the difference between my transformed touch and the original posting, i think i might need to grab the touch before the touch is dispatched to the parent, but i might be missing the correct way to transform the touch in the first place, or my kivy version is messed up.
here is the entirety

```
def on_touch_down(self, touch, *args):
    print touch.x
    print touch.y
    touch.push()
    if touch.device == 'wm_touch':
        print touch.device
        touch.apply_transform_2d(self.touch_trans)
        ret = super(MAINLEAF, self).on_touch_down(touch)
        touch.pop()
        return ret
    else:
        print touch.device
        print 'mouse or other'
        ret = super(MAINLEAF, self).on_touch_down(touch)
        touch.pop()
        return ret
```

`def touch_trans(self, x, y):
        return (x,y + 22)`

Comment: This was an issue for me when I used like kivy 1.7.2 - 1.8.0 versions in Qpython, but when I switched to normal launcher, everything was ok. It'd be good if you specified what platform and kivy version do you use and if it uses wrong y coords also on other platforms or just on a single one. I noticed some raspberry [issues](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+axis)

Comment: ive tried it on asus 10.1 inch transformer tablet windows 10 and a lenovo windows 10 both have same im using 1.7.2 and it looks like its setting the 0,0 for touch at 0.35, 0.35 percent of the screen from bottom left the delta is 0 at that point relative. Im using 1.7.2 cause i had problems installing kivy from wheel at 1.9.0 and not sure how to use minGW with it, the package sets alot of paths with kivy.bat not sure how to emulate

Comment: 1.7.2 is waaay too old. Use [Virtual Machine](https://kivy.org/#download) for quick packaging for android, or launcher(with pygame provider it's up to kivy-master if you make it yourself). For windows there's [KivyInstaller](https://github.com/KeyWeeUsr/KivyInstaller) if you can't make it, but wheels are easy to install and don't need compiler. Assuming it's a proper Windows and not Windows Mobile, of course.

Comment: thanks that batch works great i see you had a hand in making? i needed some of the functions in 1.9.0+ anyway so better i upgrade and it fixed the original touch.y problem being to high thanks so much

Comment: actually, I made it, inspired by the original kivy.bat from portable 1.8.0 package, but this is for wheels, so one file to make everything work was pretty much enough. Copy&run could be a motto. And it's MIT.

Comment: one note though the touch problem is still happening at low values of y do you know how I could transform it only for the wm_touch? I like having the newer version but cant really use well on my tablet until touch screen axis works right.

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe there is a way with [Postproc calibration](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.input.postproc.calibration.html).

Comment: based on printing touch.distance(last_touch) in which I set last_touch to the previous one the mouse coordinates are generally 25 - 30 px lower than expected, but the touch for other things(out of kivy) works perfectly could kivy be reading my hardware wrong?

Comment: It could, but I'm not familiar with this side of kivy yet. Try kivy's [IRC channel](http://webchat.freenode.net/?nick=kvuser.&channels=kivy&uio=d4) or post an issue to the repository.

Comment: well it makes it unusable for my touch devices which is why i wanted kivy to deploy to multiple devices and not rewrite everything so i might switch to something else cause even if i set a new position for the touch it registers as a touch move which means i have to override the touch move and then i dont get scrolling too many subsequent problems arise from not being able to interact with it right the first time, its almost a really good program, kivy, it looks awesome and is typed well but if i cant interact i cant use it, so unless anyone has another idea im out